# Select nodes that don't have a key with XSLT/XPath

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm using the Muenchian method to group nodes in an XML document.

As part of my output, I'd like to select all of the nodes to which I have *not* assigned a key.

I've tried

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[key('kcWWPN','')]"/>
```

but that doesn't appear to be working correctly, in that it is selecting no nodes.

Any suggestions on the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As part of my output, I'd like to select all of the nodes to which I
>   have not assigned a key.

Good question, +1.

**Here are two different, but simple solutions**:

For simplicity I will assume that we are keying only elements, but the two solutions below can naturally be extended to cover other types of nodes.

**I. Simply, define a** *counter-key*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDByClass" match="d" use="@class"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCounterKey" match="*[not(self::d)]" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="*[key('kCounterKey', .)]">
  Counter Keyed: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (borrowed from @lwburk):

```
<root>
    <d class="test">1</d>
    <d class="test">2</d>
    <d class="something">1</d>
    <q>3</q>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Counter Keyed: root
  Counter Keyed: q
```

II. **Use the set difference of all elements and all keyed elements** (the latter is found using Muenchian grouping):

This solution is simpler than the first, because one doesn't need to compose a counter-key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDByClass" match="d" use="@class"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCounterKey" match="*[not(self::d)]" use="."/>

 <xsl:variable name="vKeyedValues" select=
 "//*[generate-id()
     = generate-id(key('kDByClass', @class)[1])
     ]
      /@class
  "/>

  <xsl:variable name="vKeyedElements" select=
   "key('kDByClass', $vKeyedValues)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNonKeyedElements" select=
  "//*[not(count(.|$vKeyedElements) = count($vKeyedElements))]
  "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vNonKeyedElements">
    Not Keyed: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same, correct result is produced**:

```
Not Keyed: root
Not Keyed: q
```

**Note**: The last solution may not work when the key is not a node, but result of a function, such as `substring-before()`. In this case we simply modify the original key, so thet its `use` attribute is simply: `use="."` and use this solution with the modified original key. It can be prooven that this procedure produces the correct, wanted set of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to re-create the key that *would have been used* for the nodes you want to select and attempt to retrieve the values for that key. If the set returned for that key does not contain the current node, then it should be selected.

For example, suppose the keys were created using the concatenation of each element's `class` attribute value and its string value. We could select all elements in the document that do not have an assigned key using the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates
            select="//*[not(count(.|key('byClass', concat(@class, '|', .)))=
                            count(key('byClass', concat(@class, '|', .))))]"/>
```

Here's a complete demo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="byClass" match="d" use="concat(@class, '|', .)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="//*[not(count(.|key('byClass', concat(@class, '|', .)))=
                            count(key('byClass', concat(@class, '|', .))))]"
            mode="test"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="test">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="concat('Node ', local-name(), 
               ' not assigned a key', '&#xa;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<root>
    <d class="test">1</d>
    <d class="test">2</d>
    <d class="something">1</d>
    <q class="test">1</q>
</root>
```

It produces:

```
Node root not assigned a key
Node q not assigned a key
```

Note that the key produced by `q` is an actual key that maps to a group of nodes in the document, but this element is not in the set returned by `key('byClass', 'test|1')`, so we say that this node has not been assigned a key.

Note also that the empty string (`''`) is a perfectly valid key, which is why this doesn't do what you were hoping it would:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[key('kcWWPN', '')]"/>
```

Comment: I'm confused by this demo. It seems to apply templates to every element that has no @class attribute (and therefore no other elements have that null key value)... which also happens to be the same as every element to which no key is assigned. But have we gained anything by saying `//*[not(key('byClass', @class))]` instead of `//*[not(@class)]`? I'm not sure the former is any more general or correct. Would this technique really work for keys in general?

Comment: @LarsH - Sure, but you could have a more complex key. Mostly I think it's not a very useful question. I can't think of a practical reason to want to try this. Anything selected by the key's `match` pattern is going to have some key assigned, even if it's just the empty string. But, I guess you might not know which elements have been selected by some key's `match` pattern. That's basically what this lets you find. I think I might have a more useful demo in mind. I might update.

Comment: @LarsH - Thanks. You made me realize that my first answer was insufficient. I've completely changed the demo and its description. Hope it makes more sense now. (I still don't think this is terribly useful, but this should show that it's more than just testing if an element has some property.)

Comment: @LarsH and lwburk: See my answer for two solutions. :) My set difference was published before that of lwburk.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - We ended up with essentially the same approach. Must have been editing at the same time.

Comment: @lwburk: Yes, your solution is similar to my second solution, however it seems that my solution is just a little simpler and probably more efficient :) Also, I like even more the *counter-key* approach.